# Failover - Generic Script Resource - Logging

Tags: logging, vbscript, server, failover

I'm working on a failover setup with two cluster nodes on new servers that replaced the old servers. I am reusing the script that was used before on the old servers as a Generic Script resource - which is in fact a vbs script.

There is a logging feature used in this script, example:

```
Resource.LogInformation "Entering Script Offline"
```

I looked very thoroughly and searched the web but i am unable to find where this log is stored. Can you point me to a location/file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look in the cluster event log. You will need to use an account with local administrator privileges.

1. Start > Administrative Tools > Failover Cluster Manager
2. If the cluster you need is not displayed, right-click Failover cluster Manager, click Manage a Cluster, then pick the cluster you want
3. Expand the console tree and you will see Cluster Events

You can also view the log in the Event Viewer:

1. Go to Event Viewer
2. Expand Applications and Services Logs
3. Expand Microsoft
4. Expand Windows
5. Expand Failover Clustering

The log file is stored in system32\winevt\Logs

[TechNet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772342(v=ws.11).aspx) has more info as well.